# String split for names in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split, tuples

In my code I have a method which passes in a parameter for a name. This name will be someones full name and can contain any of the following:-

1. first name.
2. first name + last name
3. first name + middle name + last name
4. first name + middle name 1 + other middle name + lastname

We determine whether first/middle/last name is contained in the string by spaces. Thinking the best way of doing this would to check the length of the string array, if length is:

a. 1 -> return only first name: names[0]

b. 2 -> return first: names[0] and last name: names[1]

c. greater than 2 ->

-- return first name names[0]

-- last name: names.Last()

-- middle names: should be all the values in between first and last indexes

So my question is if the length is greater than 2, how do I set middle name as a concatenated string BETWEEN first and last items in the array?

Thanks

```
    private (string firstName, string middleName, string lastName) getNames(string fullName)
    {
        string[] names = fullName.Split(' ');

        string firstName = names[0];
        string middleName = "";
        string lastName = "";

        if (names.Length == 2)
        {
            lastName = names[1];
        }
        else if (names.Length > 2)
        {
            lastName = names.Last();
            middleName = ""; ?
        }

        return (firstName, middleName, lastName);
    }
```

Comment: You could use `String.Join(" ", names.Skip(1).Take(names.Count()-1))`, though that isn't terribly efficient. Having done some similar things, you might want to consider the issue of multi-part last names such as `Smith, Jr` or `Wilson II`.

Comment: As someone with a two-part last name, I hope this isn't production code.

Comment: Please don't do this; there are [too many different ways people are named](https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/). If you need a person's name, provide a text field and use whatever they type. If you absolutely must have separate family and given names (not “first” and “second” names since the family name could be first or second) provide separate fields for each. Do not try to parse names; that doesn't work.

Comment: and what if my last name is in yrArray[0]? you could use RegEx, and find a good pattern match